# Creating a 2D array in C based on user input

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, 2d

I am trying to create a dynamic 2D array for a game that is dependent on user input. I currently have a function that is allocating memory shown here:

```
void mallocGrid(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i; 
    char* height;
    char* width;

    int inputHeight = strtol(argv[3], &height, 10);
    int inputWidth = strtol(argv[4], &width, 10);

    char** gridArray = malloc(sizeof(char*) * inputHeight);
    for (i = 0; i < inputHeight; i++){
        gridArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * inputWidth);
    }
}
```

I have another function to popultate this grid array with the '.' character. Here is what I currently have:

```
void gridInit(int argc, char** argv) {
    char gridArray[MAX_COLUMN][MAX_ROW];
    int i, j;
    char* height;
    char* width;

    int inputHeight = strtol(argv[3], &height, 10);
    int inputWidth = strtol(argv[4], &width, 10);

    for(i=0; i < inputWidth; i++) {
        for(j=0; j < inputHeight; j++) {
            gridArray[i][j]= '.';
            printf("%c\n", gridArray[i][j]);
        }
        fputc('\n', stdout); 
    }
}
```

However, when the user inputs a height of 2 and a width of 3, this is what shows up:

```
.
.

.
.

.
.
```

but I was expecting to get:

```
..
..
..
```

Is this the right way to dynamically create a grid that can be overwritten as the game progresses?

Comment: Your output has nothing to do with how you dynamically allocate this array, and solely depends on what you pass to function `printf`. You can get the desired output by removing the `\n` in the first call to `printf`.

Comment: `char **` is not a 2D array nor can it point to one or be used as one! And used self-explanatory names for arguments. `argc` and `argv` are more than useless, they are missleading.

Answer (score 0):

there is no relation of 2-D dynamic array & it's output..in what manner you want to get your output is upto you..remove \n from printf("%c\n", gridArray[i][j]); statement and you will get your output as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

[too long for a comment]

The two definitions of `gridArray` in here

```
void mallocGrid(int argc, char** argv) {
  ...

  char** gridArray = malloc(sizeof(char*) * inputHeight);
```

and here

```
void gridInit(int argc, char** argv) {
  char gridArray[MAX_COLUMN][MAX_ROW];

  ...
```

are independent. Each defines its own variable. The have nothing in common but the name. Even the types are different.

Both variable's definition "disappear" the moment the function is left.

---

> I am trying to create a dynamic 2D array for a game that is dependent on user input.

You do not do this here:

```
  char gridArray[MAX_COLUMN][MAX_ROW];
```

Comment: Well, the `malloc`ed objects don't disappear. They leak, because they are not reachable from the code anymore.